# multiple objects of the same class "Minesweeper"

Tags: minesweeper

im new in java and my question might be stupid but i really dont know how to solve this problem, im making a Minesweeper and im using javafx, im using a class for the mines, so im using a "stackPane" and im puting it inside a grid, the problem i have is that i don't know hot to make multiples instances of it, and i have no clue how to start, im makinga 10*10 board and the mines are suposed to apear randomly, so im using "math.random" to decide if one space will be empti or if it will have a mine, i hope some one out there can help me

---

well i find a solution, but the thing i dont know how to do now is how to set a "setaction" for each button, im trying to put  setonactio(new eventhandler() ...
here is my code:

```
 package buscaminas2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author ALIENWARE R4
 */
public class Buscaminas2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("buscaminas");





        GridPane mainGrid = new GridPane(); 





    GridPane flowPane = new GridPane();
    flowPane.setPadding(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    flowPane.setVgap(2);
    flowPane.setHgap(2);
    //flowPane.setPrefWrapLength(210);




    HBox score = new HBox();



    Button btn = new Button();


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {//-----------------bob the constructor------------------//

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
               int abc = (int)(Math.random()*10);
               System.out.print(abc);

               if( abc > 2)
               {
                 btn = new Button(" ");
                 btn.setId(STYLESHEET_MODENA);
                btn.setPrefSize(35, 35);
                flowPane.add(btn, i, j);
                flowPane.getChildren().get(i);


               }
               else
               {
                    StackPane boomb = new StackPane();//---------------------bombs--------------------//
                    boomb.setPrefSize(35, 35);
                    Label num = new Label("X"); 
                    num.setPrefSize(40, 40);
                    boomb.getChildren().add(num);
                    Button xyz = new Button();
                    xyz.setPrefSize(40, 40);
                     boomb.getChildren().add(xyz);

                       flowPane.add(boomb, i, j);// agrega bombas en xy agregando "boomb" en el grid









               }



            }



    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(flowPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? It's not very clear. 
If you can't explain maybe add your code with the problematic part

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)